# How to enable a non root user to substitute the file /etc/hosts by cp command, without the sudo command?

Tags: command-line, permissions, lubuntu, sudo

On my lubuntu 22.04 I need to change the file `/etc/hosts`. To do that I would to execute the command:

```
> /usr/bin/cp /path/to/new_hosts /etc/hosts
```

by a non root user without the sudo command. To do this I have add the following line to the file `/etc/sudoers`:

```
<username> ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/cp /path/to/new_hosts /etc/hosts
```

I have checked the correct syntax of `/etc/sudoers` by the command:

```
> sudo visudo -c /etc/sudoers
```

The output of the command is:

```
/etc/sudoers: parsed OK
/etc/sudoers.d/10-installer: parsed OK
/etc/sudoers.d/README: parsed OK
/etc/sudoers.d/kdesu-sudoers: parsed OK
```

The message `/etc/sudoers: parsed OK` assures me that the syntax of `/etc/sudoers` is correct.

When I execute the `cp` command by a terminal the result is `Permission denied`.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: You need to use `sudo` to use the `sudoedit` or modify any files in `/etc` (such as `sudoers` though I'd recommend using `visudo` so changes are validated before saving! as don't forget any error in the file is treated as a EOF thus subsequent lines are ignored; meaning you risk losing `sudo` access on the system if you make a mistake)

Comment: @guiverc I have edited the question according to to your comment.

Comment: You can't get `cp` to work without `sudo` by editing `sudo` configs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to run your command with `sudo`:

```bash
sudo /usr/bin/cp /path/to/new_hosts /etc/hosts
```

Otherwise, the `sudoers` file won't be considered.

Comment: Perfect, It was 1 day that I was looking for this answer. Thank you very much